# Is there a "reverse sudo"?

Tags: shell-script

Let's say I have a script that will be executed on various machines with root privileges, but I want to execute certain commands within that script without root.

Is that possible?

Comment: The usual way is to run the script as the invoking user and use `sudo` for those commands which needs it. `sudo` caches the credentials, so it should prompt at most once.

Comment: Yes, it's called "switch user and do", or `sudo` for short.

Comment: Reverse sudo? You mean, sudont?

Comment: I tried "odus", but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Both [`su`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/su.1.html) and [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/sudo.8.html) can do this. They run a command as another user; by default that "another user" is root, but it can be any user. For example,

```
sudo -u www-data ls
```

will run `ls` as the user `www-data`.

**However...**

The usual way is to run the script as the invoking user and use `sudo` for those commands which need it. `sudo` caches the credentials, so it should prompt at most once.

Comment: `sudo` will only cache the credentials for a limited time; if the script spends enough time executing non-root commands these cached credentials may be lost.

Answer (score 31):

`sudo` exports environment variables `SUDO_COMMAND`, `SUDO_GID`,  `SUDO_UID`, and `SUDO_USER`.

You can use `SUDO_USER` or `SUDO_UID` to get back to the invoking user:

```
sudo -u "$SUDO_USER" an_unprivileged_command
```

Answer (score 4):

`sudo` is a souped-up version of `su` with better access controls.  If you're already running as `root`, `su` will do it with no fuss:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo -n "Script User:          " && id -un
echo -n "Other user:           " && su blrfl -c "id -un"
echo -n "Back to script user:  " && id -un
```

When run, you get this:

```
Script User:          root
Other user:           blrfl
Back to script user:  root
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [AlexP’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353207/86925) that you should generally run as non-root and only invoke sudo only for commands that need it. Whitelisting is always safer than blacklisting.

In addition to AlexP’s answer: You might want to invoke `sudo` at the very top of the script, to make sure that you don’t execute a number of operations until you realize that the user isn’t permitted to run `sudo`, and create a broken state. Therefore, I recommend to put the following at the top of scripts which need `sudo` at some point:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo true || exit 1

# … other code …
```

This will immediately ask for the password (if necessary) and abort executing the script if `sudo` fails.